# Get multiple files from meta box "file_advanced"

Tags: wordpress

On my WordPress site I created a meta box to upload multiple files with:

```
array(
    'name'      => 'upload',
    'id'        => 'test_multiple_upload',
    'type'      => 'file_advanced',
    'max_file_size' => '2mb',
    'multiple'  => true)
```

When I try to get the file on my template I supposed to have an array with the files but I get only the first file.

```
$files = (get_post_meta(get_the_id() , 'test_multiple_upload',true)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: what do you get when you remove `true` from the last argument? And how are you uploading files? Via `wp.media` or?

Comment: bingo! 
if I remove true it works! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead of your get_post_meta() function, to get the array of images.

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$meta = get_post_custom($postid);
$files = $meta['test_multiple_upload'];// this is the main array try to print_r() this variable to seen the array
```

And also into your code

```
$files = (get_post_meta(get_the_id() , 'test_multiple_upload',true)
```

There are many error
first error is ,**get_the_id()** should be **get_the_ID()** 
second , you have extra starting  bracket at the beginning of the **get_post_meta**, please check.

Thanks